# Auto increment ID Insert Data ORMLITE

Tags: android, database, insert, ormlite

I'm new to Android and I have problem with ORMLITE.

For example let's say I have this table:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "accounts")
public class Account {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)
    private String name;
    …
```

and I want to add new data into my table **without setting id**.

I tried this way:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "accounts")
public class Account {

@DatabaseField(generatedId = true,allowGeneratedIdInsert=true)
private int id;

@DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)
private String name;
…



> Account acc = new Account();
> 
> acc.setName("Example");
> 
> AccountDao.createOrupdate(acc);
```

Here I can't insert acc into my database because acc id is zero. I want to generate id. Can I use autoincrement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here i can't insert acc into my database because acc id is zero. I want to generate id. Can i use autoincrement ?

So to quote the javadocs for the [`allowGeneratedIdInsert` field in `@DatabaseField`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#allowGeneratedIdInsert%28%29):

> If this is set to true then inserting an object with the ID field already set will not override it with a generated-id. This is useful when you have a table where items sometimes have IDs and sometimes need them generated. This only works if the database supports this behavior and if `generatedId()` is also true for the field.

So if you have `acc.id` set to a non-0 value, it should be inserted into the database *with* the id from `acc`.  If you want `acc` to get an auto-generated id then you should just set `acc.id` to be 0.

For an example, you could take a look at the [ORMLite Android test class](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-android-tests/blob/master/src/com/j256/ormlite/android/AndroidJdbcBaseDaoImplTest.java).  Search for the `testCreateWithAllowGeneratedIdInsert()` method which has code like:

```
AllowGeneratedIdInsert foo = new AllowGeneratedIdInsert();
assertEquals(1, dao.create(foo));
AllowGeneratedIdInsert result = dao.queryForId(foo.id);
assertEquals(foo.id, result.id);
...

AllowGeneratedIdInsert foo3 = new AllowGeneratedIdInsert();
foo3.id = 10002;
assertEquals(1, dao.create(foo3));
result = dao.queryForId(foo3.id);
assertEquals(foo3.id, result.id);
```

NOTE: the docs mention that this only works if the database supports it but Sqlite is one of those databases.

Answer (score 0):

Use Wrapper class instead of int

```
@DatabaseField(id = true)
private Integer id;
```